# li works inline but not otherwise

Tags: html-lists, custom-lists

my html is

```
<div id="heading1">
    <ul class="heading">
        <li>Geelong</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and css is

```
.heading {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-image: url('img/stationary/marker.png');
}
```

If I do the css inline it works but not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

With that code:

```
<div id="heading1">
    <ul class="heading">
        <li>Geelong</li>
    </ul>
</div>

.heading{
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-image: url('https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
}
```

The list is displaying correctly with Google logo as bullet.
It seems that your problem is the image's URL that is wrong. You may verify that it points to an image that exists (think that it's a relative link)

Comment: You just need to put the right URL and verify that your browser has the right to access to the image